# Tag Info vs. Tag Wiki: be clear they are NOT the same

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt, terminology

Here the user has just edited a "Tag Info" item.
They then read about a seemingly additional "Tag Wiki" that they might want to edit.

[image: Tag Info vs. Tag Wiki]

As Tag Info and Tag Wiki are probably NOT in fact referring to the same thing, the language on the page needs to be tightened up to avoid confusing users.

Comment: [tag:tag-wiki] and [tag:tag-wiki-excerpt] (what you called "tag info", often referred to as "usage guidance" or "tag excerpt") are not the same thing. The excerpt is the text you see when hovering over a tag or clicking on it. It has a limit of 500 characters and no formatting. The tag wiki can be much longer and formatted in markdown. You only see it when going to the tag info. For an example see the tag excerpt and tag wiki of [tag-wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-wiki/info).

Comment: On a slightly ironic sidenote, [tag:tag-wiki-excerpt] does not have a tag wiki, only an excerpt.

Comment: OK, I inserted two big NOTs as everybody says they are NOT the same. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 10):

This workflow is somewhat confusing and could definitely benefit from an overhaul. It's easy to forget to question how informative the UI is when you already know how to use the page. So, let's start with understanding the entry points and UI of the page itself:

### Feature review:

Visiting the tag info page for a tag with no content looks like this:

[image: About 1917 tag on Movies & TV. The Tag Info has two separate boxes that indicate information is missing - "usage guidance" and "tag wiki". The usage guidance warning is a box with a white background and the tag wiki warning has an orange background. Each warning describes the purpose of the information and the tag wiki guidance explains who can propose guidance.]

You can see this differs from your screenshot, which shows only the orange lower box while your suggested edit is held in the upper, white box.

Here is the header of a tag page:

[image: "Questions tagged 1917" on Movies & TV header section. Below the heading, there is text that reads "The 1917 tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?" where "help us create it" is a link. There's also a "Learn more..." link]

Here's what a tag card shows when you hover over a tag when the tag has no excerpt:

[image: A small modal with the link text "Help us edit this wiki" above buttons for following and ignoring the tag.]

I'm not sure how you got to the tag wiki editor.

- You could have started at the tag info page similar to the first image above which, somewhat unintuitively, shows two distinct boxes with missing info and how to create it and then clicked the button to "Create tag info" at the bottom of the page.
- You could have gone directly from the tag page for the tag using the "help us create it" link.
- You could have gone by clicking the "Help us edit this wiki" text on the tag card when you hovered over it somewhere on the site.

If the first, while not completely obvious, you at least get a hint there's two separate spots for text and the purpose of that text. If one of the other two, there's a lot less information to help you out.

Now, let's look at the tag wiki editor page:

[image: "Editing tag info for 1917" page. There are two separate text boxes, the upper one is labeled "Usage guidance (excerpt)" with the note "(plain text only, no Markdown formatting)" and "Enter at least 20 characters" and the lower text box has a text formatting bar. On the right side of the page, there's a info box titled "What are Tag Wikis?" that explains the purpose of the two boxes.]

While I'm totally willing to accept that the yellow box on the right wasn't visible to you - it's tucked away below everything on mobile or other narrow screens and it's kinda easy to miss if you're just expecting it to be the usual right sidebar - but I think there is plenty of guidance available, it's just hard to find.

The rest of the page is... inscrutable and needs a lot of work. Why does the "Usage guidance (excerpt)" box have a heading but the full tag wiki editor doesn't? If I didn't already know how to use this page, I would be really confused by this presentation.

### Recommended remediations:

Bare minimum, put a buffer between the two editor boxes and add a header to the lower one labeling it "Tag Wiki".

Once that's changed, start considering whether some of that info could be closer to the text entry fields. The short sentence about the usage guidance could easily live between the heading and the text box without changing the page height much. The longer info about the wiki could be split up so that a sentence briefly covers the purpose of the wiki in plain text. The yellow box can be repurposed to say "How to write a good Tag Wiki?" and focus on that information alone.

Comment: It used to be that on tag wiki pages, the excerpt would be collapsed by default and hidden behind a "show excerpt" link. I'm not sure when it was changed to simply show both - I think it was during the 2015 major site redesign.

Comment: Thanks for working on this. I hope your ideas get approved.

Answer (score 0):

Tag Info and Tag Wiki are not exactly the same, will try to explain from what I know and the way I see it.

Tag Info means information about the tag, while Tag Wiki refers to the tag wiki excerpt and full tag wiki posts that you can create and edit.

Comment: from the language in the [edit tag info page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/3303) I would say the tag info consists of the excerpt and the tag wiki.

Comment: OK fine. Please somebody fix the orange message to make it clear that the two are separate and that the user has just edited only one.  Also the user doesn't see any button to edit the second. The button must not be visible because the user does not have enough rep yet. Well then it should be visible, but just greyed out.

Comment: @DanJacobson My answer tries to clear this up somewhat. The editors for both are on the same page, it's just really poorly designed. While my answer doesn't address the orange box, I think the editor page itself was a major contributor to your confusion.

Comment: @Catija Thanks for working on this. I hope your ideas get approved.